# Shared element transition between button and toolbar content

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-animation, shared-element-transition

Shared element transitions between fragments in navigation component is working.

But if I tryed to implement shared element transition from fragment view to toolbar content means it is not working.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

MainFragment.kt

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (v!!.id) {
        R.id.view_balance_btn -> {
            val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(
                view_balance_btn to "view_balance"
            )
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_viewBalanceFragment, null, null, extras)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewBalanceFragment.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
}
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
...

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/view_balance_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View balance"
        android:transitionName="view_balance"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/send_money_btn" />
...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

toolbar_content.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
...
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ivHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Back"
        android:transitionName="view_balance"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tvTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: There is no transition between toolbar and fragment as toolbar not change during fragment transition

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Yes understand. Any other solution to achieve that?